# Page size in crystal report

Tags: visual-studio-2005, crystal-reports

I am doing project using `vb.net` and access its windows application I need to produce a crystal report of customized paper size. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Print Setup dialog in Crystal Reports. You choose specific printer and set its properties, including paper size. Usually CR remembers these settings, unless application doesn't overwrite them.

Note that I've not yet found a way to set custom paper size, not specifying printer itself. Even in code that is not easy, if even possible. We need sometimes to design reports for POS systems - almost impossible without having POS printer on hand.